# Outer Join multible tables keeping all rows in common colums

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm quite new to SQL - hope you can help:

I have several tables that all have 3 columns in common: `ObjNo`, `Date(year-month)`, `Product`.
Each table has 1 other column, that represents an economic value (`sales`, `count`, `netsales`, `plan` ..)

I need to join all tables on the 3 common columns giving. The outcome must have one row for each existing combination of the 3 common columns. Not every combination exists in every table.

If I do full outer joins, I get `ObjNo`, `Date`, etc. for each table, but only need them once.

How can I achieve this?

```
+--------------+-------+--------+---------+-----------+
|   tblCount   |       |        |         |           |
+--------------+-------+--------+---------+-----------+
|              | ObjNo | Date   | Product | count     |
|              | 1     | 201601 | Snacks  | 22        |
|              | 2     | 201602 | Coffee  | 23        |
|              | 4     | 201605 | Tea     | 30        |
|              |       |        |         |           |
| tblSalesPlan |       |        |         |           |
|              | ObjNo | Date   | Product | salesplan |
|              | 1     | 201601 | Beer    | 2000      |
|              | 2     | 201602 | Sancks  | 2000      |
|              | 5     | 201605 | Tea     | 2000      |
|              |       |        |         |           |
|              |       |        |         |           |
| tblSales     |       |        |         |           |
|              | ObjNo | Date   | Product | Sales     |
|              | 1     | 201601 | Beer    | 1000      |
|              | 2     | 201602 | Coffee  | 2000      |
|              | 3     | 201603 | Tea     | 3000      |
+--------------+-------+--------+---------+-----------+
```

Thx
Devon

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: `tblCount   
ObjNo Date Product count
1 201601 Snacks 22
2 201602 Coffee 23
4 201605 Tee 30
   
tblSalesPlan   
ObjNo Date Product salesplan
1 201601 Beer 2000
2 201602 Sancks 2000
5 201605 Tee 2000
   
   
tblSales   
ObjNo Date Product Sales
1 201601 Beer 1000
2 201602 Coffee 2000
3 201603 Tee 3000
`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using `SELECT * FROM...` which is giving you every field from every table. You probably only want to get the values from one table, so you should be explicit about which fields you want to include in the results.

If you're not sure which table is going to have a record for each case (i.e. there is not guaranteed to be a record in any particular table) you can use the `COALESCE` function to get the first non-null value in each case.

```
SELECT COALESCE(tbl1.ObjNo, tbl2.ObjNo, tbl3.ObjNo) AS ObjNo, ....
    tbl1.Sales, tbl2.Count, tbl3.Netsales
```

Comment: thx - exactly what I need. I need all uncommon fields from all tables.

Comment: Yeah you need to explicitly list each uncommon field in the `SELECT` field list, as per the example in the answer. There is no shortcut that can return you the uncommon fields without also giving you all of the common fields multiple times.

Comment: Its not about the uncommon fields - I need them all. Its about the common ones. Here I use COALESCE now